# How to detect blocking on doubleclick adsense(DFP) code using javascript?

Tags: javascript, adsense, double-click, google-dfp, adblock

A lot of people use plugins like Adblock to avoid banners on websites. If you can detect that plugin, you can easily display an image or text of your preference.

I have Try For this Code

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ( typeof(window.google_jobrunner) === "undefined" ) {
        alert("adblcoker is Enabled");
      } else {
        alert("adblacker is not founed")
      }
    }, 2000);  
  };
</script>
```

But This Code only detect on google AdSense code.

How to detect on "doubleclick adsense (DFP) code"?

Comment: See here:
https://michilehr.de/adblocker-detection-when-using-google-doubleclick-for-dfp-and-tracking-to-google-analytics/

Comment: I have already used for this code but it was not working.

Comment: It is not mentioned in your question, so i was thinking you might have missed it.